# Como manipular header de request com Filter

Tags: java, java-ee, http

Como alterar, remover ou adicionar um `header` de uma requisição em uma aplicação Web usando `Filter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para recuperar um *header* da requisição `HTTP` você pode usar os métodos [`getHeader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeader(java.lang.String)), [`getHeaders`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getHeaders(java.lang.String)), além de outros utilitários como [`getDateHeader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getDateHeader(java.lang.String))

Já para adicionar ou alterar é um pouco mais trabalhoso, já que diretamente você não consegue fazer isto. Para isto é necessário um *wrapper*/*decorator* que terá os *headers* customizados, mas lembre-se, os cabeçalhos originais da requisição não serão alterados, você apenas está *decorando* a requisição e mantendo neste *wrapper* os cabeçalhos alterados e incluídos.

Para facilitar já está disponível um *wrapper* base que você pode extendê-lo, o [`HttpServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequestWrapper.html). Dele iremos alterar a forma que são obtidos os cabeçalho, então iremos sobrescrever `getHeader` e `getHeaderNames`.

Vamos então construir um `CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper`, algo desta forma:

```java
public class CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {

    private final Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(final HttpServletRequest request) {
        super(request);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration<String> getHeaderNames() {
        final HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) this.getRequest();
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        list.addAll(Collections.list(request.getHeaderNames()));
        list.addAll(headers.keySet());

        return Collections.enumeration(list);
    }

    @Override
    public String getHeader(final String name) {
        if (headers.containsKey(name)) {
            return headers.get(name);
        }
        return super.getHeader(name);
    }

    public void addHeader(final String name, final String value) {
        headers.put(name, value);
    }

}
```

Perceba que estamos usando um mapa, então estou assumindo que teremos apenas um valor para cada nome de cabeçalho, a `key` do mapa. Você pode adicionar um outro tipo de dado de forma a permitir nomes repetidos para cabeçalhos, caso seja necessário.

No seu filtro ficaria algo desta forma:

```java
@Override
public void doFilter(final ServletRequest request, final ServletResponse response, final FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (request instanceof HttpServletRequest) {
        final HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper wrapper = new CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper(httpRequest);
        wrapper.addHeader("CUSTOM-HEADER", "value");
        chain.doFilter(wrapper, response);
    } else {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Este *wrapper* considera apenas requisições `HTTP`, ou seja, que por padrão possuem cabeçalhos. Caso você precise não de apenas requisições `HTTP`, mas todas as outras [`ServletRequest`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html) dê uma olhada em [`ServletRequestWrapper`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequestWrapper.html), você poderá manter cabeçalhos para elas também de forma parecida como fizemos em `CustomHttpServletRequestWrapper`.

Comment: @Luidne conseguiu com esta abordagem? Precisa de alguma outra ajuda? Caso tenha ajudado, considere aceitar a resposta. Obrigado

Comment: Testei e não alterou o *header* que escolhi (`SOAPAction`). Essa minha pergunta é referente a uma migração aplicação Java Web  para outro servidor de aplicação Java. Glassfish para Wildfly. Onde o primeiro aceita requisições com cabeçalho `SOAPAction` com conteúdo e o segundo só aceita sem conteúdo. Essa alteração no cabeçalho seria para não quebrar a compatibilidade em aplicações em produção que enviam `SOAPAction` com conteúdo.

Comment: @Luídne então cara, como disse na resposta, você não consegue alterar os *headers* da *request* original, o que conseguimos fazer é encapsular a requisição e neste *wrapper* alterar os cabeçalhos. Então, você tem que garantir que é a requisição encapsulada que irá chegar às suas outras camadas/interações. Não sei como está sua aplicação, se precisa alterar é na aplicação ou algum componente do *container*, mas isto é o que você consegue fazer.

Comment: Entendi. Valeu!